# getting the domain address of an email address

Tags: php, substring

I have an issue of getting the domain address of an email, In the substring this is the code.

```
$to=$son_im_email;//udemesamuel256@gmail.com
$goto_small=strtolower($to);
//this is what i want to achieve is just to get the 'GMAIL.COM' from the email address.
```

Comment: You have three valid answers. Consider accepting one and maybe even give an upvote for those who you think are valid to show some appreciation. You Question lacks effort already while the answers did show effort. Be a nice person please ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

`$email  = 'test@example.com';
$domain = substr(strstr($email, '@'),1);
echo $domain;`

Also try

`$email  = 'test@gmail.com';
$domain = explode('@',$email);
$domain = $domain[1];
echo $domain ;`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using "explode" or a regular expression:

```
<?php
  $address = 'someuser@my.smalldomain.info';
  $details = parse_url('mailto://'.$address);
  var_dump($details);
?>
```

The output:

```
array(3) {
  'scheme' =>
  string(6) "mailto"
  'host' =>
  string(19) "my.smalldomain.info"
  'user' =>
  string(8) "someuser"
}
```

So you can use the domain name as `$details['host']`.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation from https://www.php.net/preg_match

```
$matched = preg_match("@.+$", $goto_small, $matches);
```

`$matched` will be an int telling you whether `@anything` could be found, and `$matches` will be an array whose first element will be the `@` and everything after it, if the function suceeded.